# Struts2 action not working copy paste url another tab it works

Tags: java, struts2

when I submit the button first time , it will hit the action. its not woking but when I copy url to another tab it works or hit the address bar it works

**struts.xml**

```
 <action name="ViewAllEmployeesPrinting"  method="employeeSelectPrintingtMethod"
                     class="volo.tms.printing.ViewAllEmployeesPrinting">
                <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>
                <result name="success">/printingjob/ViewAllEmployeesPrinting.jsp</result>
            </action>
            <action name="viewPrintingReportflag"  class="volo.tms.printing.ViewAllEmployeesPrinting" method="viewPrintingReportf">
                <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>
                <result name="input">/printingjob/ViewAllEmployeesPrinting.jsp</result>
                 <result name="success" type="chain">fetchJobList</result>
            </action>
```

**jsp file**

```
<s:form action="viewPrintingReportflag" method="post">
                <table>
                    <tr> <td><label for="addnewc">Client Name:</label></td>
                        <td>
                            <s:select label="Client Name" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Client" 
                                      list="clientNameList" name="clientNames" theme="simple"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> <td> From Date*: </td><td><input type="text" id="datefrom" name="datefrom" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> <td>To Date*: </td><td><input type="text" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> <td> </td><td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
<s:form>
```

and **java file**

```
public class ViewAllEmployeesPrinting extends ActionSupport implements Preparable {

    private List<String> clientNameList;
    private String clientNames;
    private Date datefrom;    
    private Date dateTo; 

    public List<String> getClientNameList() {
        return clientNameList;
    }

    public void setClientNameList(List<String> clientNameList) {
        this.clientNameList = clientNameList;
    }

    public String getClientNames() {
        return clientNames;
    }

    public void setClientNames(String clientNames) {
        this.clientNames = clientNames;
    }

    public Date getDatefrom() {
        return datefrom;
    }

    public void setDatefrom(Date datefrom) {
        this.datefrom = datefrom;
    }

    public Date getDateTo() {
        return dateTo;
    }

    public void setDateTo(Date dateTo) {
        this.dateTo = dateTo;
    }

    public String employeeSelectPrintingtMethod() {

        return "success";
    }

     public void prepare() throws Exception {
        clientNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        clientNameList = ViewClientNameDao.viewClientNameList();
    }

    public String viewPrintingReportf(){
        System.out.println("success");       
        return "success";
    }
}
```

i cannot find reason action not getting after i submit button

Comment: Can you turn off javascript in the browser ans see if it works?

Comment: Define not working? What is happening?